# Flutter app crashing after using it for a while. The main issue seems to be a memory error. But what could be the specific reason?

Tags: flutter, dart, memory

I am building a news application. The API that I'm consuming is from https://newsapi.org/

The application crashes after using it for a while. Till now I've just created a general news section above which one can choose to open another news section by category. I think the problem could be that the images are too big and I have always at least two active screens: the principal one and the one that appears after Navigator.push function. Besides that, every news tile has this onTap function, where you can open a web view of the whole article.

Here is what appears in my log after the crash.

> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> W/Adreno-GSL(29171): <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2339>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
> E/Adreno-GSL(29171): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2209>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
> Lost connection to device.

Comment: As you don't provide a code snippet of what you are doing with this API, I presume you are storing so much data that the memory of the device is overflowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized I was using extreme huge asset images for things like FadeInImage widgets. Turning the images size around 500 pixels or similar solved my issue. The images that I was getting from the api were completely ok.

Comment: can you please share how you found that asset was an issue? This issue occurs to me only on a 32-bit device in a random scenario. I'm trying to identify the issue with dev tools. but I can't able to find anything.

Comment: to be honest I just guessed it and got rid of the big assets and tried to run the app again and did not see that behavior again. This gave me the hint: gsl_memory_alloc_pure